# iPhone Spotlight not showing results

Tags: iphone, spotlight

A few OS updates ago (maybe as far back at the first 9.x version?), Spotlight search on my iPhone has performed very inconsistently.  I can enter the same search string several times, but I'd say no more than 50% of the time do any results appear.

I've tried reseting & restoring my iPhone, but the problem persists.

Is this a known regression or something I can try to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I too have had this problem since I updated. Usually I find it's just some serious lag ad if you wait it out results will show up. If not there may be a bigger problem with your iPhone. Or you might just need to do a good old software update!